# Regex: Is it possible to reference all of the repeats of a capture?

Tags: regex

Consider this regex:  `^([0-9]+)(?: ([-\+/%\*]) ([0-9]+))+$`

In english, it says "a number, followed by one or more of (an operation and another number)".

Matched against a subject like `5 + 4` that regex produces $1 = 5, $2 = +, and $3 = 4.

Matched against this subject:  `5 + 4 * 3`, I get  $1 = 5, $2 = *, and $3 = 3.

In this latter case, can I capture and reference the + and the 4 ?

In other words, when using a quantifier in the regex, can I reference sequences other than the final captured sequence?

If the answer depends n the language or platform, I guess I am most interested in:

- C, with PCRE
- Javascript
- .NET, with System.Text.RegularExpressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you would use

```
myMatch.Groups[1].Captures
```

Comment: But if you're trying to parse mathematical expressions, forget about using regexes, even in .NET.  That way lies madness. :-/